# Python: Comparing values in a defaultdict(set)

Tags: python

I have a `defalutdict(set)` that stores a set of users, and for each user a set of events, and a timestamp for each event. What I need to do is check the timestamp of the item in the defaultdict and if it falls outside a specific time then remove it from the dict.

The defaultdict[player] looks like this:

```
set([('event1', <function timestampToEpoch at 0x102f8b758>), 
     ('event3', <function timestampToEpoch at 0x102f8b758>),
     ('event2', <function timestampToEpoch at 0x102f8b758>)]))
```

The code I'm trying to use looks like:

```
def removeUnique(player, f_Type, num_seconds, ts):
    curTime = timestampToEpoch(ts)
    for e in uniqueFishes[player] if e <= curTime - num_seconds
            uniqueFishes[player].remove(e)
    print uniqueFishes[player]
```

Comment: Whats the problem with your code? Is there a stacktrace?

Comment: I get `  File "fiveMinIntervCnSnC.py", line 73
    for e in uniqueFishes[player] if e >= (curTime - num_seconds)
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Dumb typo edit -  I actually want to remove items that are older (not newer) so I changed `for e in uniqueFishes[player] if e >= curTime - num_seconds` to `for e in uniqueFishes[player] if e <= curTime - num_seconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your if function in the loop.

Your `e` variable is not a timestamp, but a tuple of a string and a timestamp. You get the timestamp with selecting the 2nd item of the tuple: `e[1]`.

You modify an iterable (`uniqueFishes`) while iterating over it. It is always a bad idea. Easiest (but not most efficient) solution for this is to iterate over a COPY of the original set while modifying the set itself.

```
def removeUnique(player,f_Type,num_seconds,ts):
   curTime = timestampToEpoch(ts)
   for e in uniqueFishes[player].copy():
      if e[1] >= curTime - num_seconds: 
         uniqueFishes[player].remove(e)
   print uniqueFishes[player]
```

Comment: This definitely worked (or got me close enough to figure out my next little bug) - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned the two errors:

1)  line 73 for e in uniqueFishes[player] if e >= (curTime - num_seconds) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

2) Set changed size during iteration

.

change

```
for e in uniqueFishes[player] if e >= curTime - num_seconds
        uniqueFishes[player].remove(e)
```

to :

```
to_remove_set = set()
for e in uniqueFishes[player]:
    if e[1] >= (curTime - num_seconds):
        to_remove_set.add(e)

# modify your set after iteration.
uniqueFisihes[player] -= to_remove_set
```

Comment: See above, but i get this `I end up getting RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration` which I assume is because it removes an object from the defaultdict as it's going through it

Comment: @Mike  you can add the to be removed elements in a temporary set, call it to_remove_set,   uniqueFishes[player] = uniqueFishes[player] - to_remove_set  will update your set, you should do the subtraction after the for loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[uniqueFishes[player].remove(e) for e in uniqueFishes[player] 
 if e >= (curTime - num_seconds)]
```

Comment: I end up getting `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`

Comment: Why use a list comprehension if you're not building a list?

Comment: Correct, it won't work for a set.  Of course list comprehension is much faster than for loops.  Question: Why use a set instead of a list in this example.  Why would the data be duplicated and thus need a set?

Comment: Yes - so there are multiple "players" and so there are multiple instances that need to keep tack of `uniqueFishes[player1]`, `uniqueFishes[player2]` etc